# Footer doesnt go all the way to the bottom

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

My footer doesnt go all the way to the bottom.
I have put my code in a js fiddle for people to have a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/q2pd5/

My problem is better viewed on the actual page:
http://dev.madhousecreative.co.uk/
or on the full screen result of the jsfiddle its obvious also.

As It is clear to see, underneath the footer there is a white gap, and I dont know why it is appearing.

I have alot of floats in here but I have tried clearing them where necessary.

Have also tried to sticky footer as suggested in some other questions answers but that doesn't work either.

As far as I am aware it is on all browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
overflow: hidden
```

to #footer in your css. This is a little trick that often gets overlooked. Basically overflow: hidden allows your div to size vertically based on it's contents.

Comment: What actually was the problem tho? Do you know?

Comment: @RyanMurphy, Yes and no! when you use firebug or IE developer toolbar you cannot see the div even though it has content. It technically has a height 0px. adding the overflow: hidden allows it to size to it's content (height). Once it sizes it allows the page to render correctly because it has a height. I can't tell you the actual mechanics of what the problem was. As I matter of course all my divs are clear: both; overflow: hidden (unless they're floating). Hope this helps out a bit.

Comment: @RyanMurphy, Can you mark as answer if this was the answer. I haven't had one yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't cleared the `float`s of the lists in the footer. [Clear it](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) with `overflow: hidden;` on the footer like this:

```
 #footer {
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Great that worked thanks. Dont you normally clear floats with clear:both; tho?

Comment: @RyanMurphy yeah, it works as well, but sometimes you would have to add unnecessary HTML markup to apply the `clear` to. By clearing with the `overflow` property you avoid this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is not being properly cleared. Try it with a clearfix like so:

```
#footer:before, #footer:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
#footer:after {
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    zoom:1; /* ie fix */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The footer has `height: 200px;` specified, chopping of the background image. The footer actually extends to the bottom of the window, but the last item in the list can't be seen because it is white text on white background.

In other words, setting `overflow: hidden` doesn't fix it alone, it just chops of the rest of the footer. Remove the `height: 200px` as well, and it works.